# What is the name of a person who likes high quality items?

Tags: attributive-nouns

What is the name of a person who likes high quality items, not necessarily the most expensive, but the best for the money perhaps.

Comment: I mean, who doesn't want the best value for money?

Comment: @NVZ I think he is referring to the act of being aware of the price/benefit

Answer (score 4):

I would say "Connoisseur" is close, in particular in the sense of [Merriam-Webster's second definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/connoisseur)

> one who enjoys with discrimination and appreciation of subtleties.
>   *"a connoisseur of fine wines*"

Comment: Good word based on the title of the post, but the body differs in focus from solely "high quality items" to "high quality in relation to cost".

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a noun-phrase, I can come up with

> - **"a conscientious shopper"**,
> - **"an educated consumer"**,
> - **"a price-conscious shopper"**

These are not specific for quality versus price. They can be used for those buyers who are concerned with environmental and labor issues too.

Comment: Or an *educated consumer*.

Comment: My trademark on that term expired long ago. Go for it!

Comment: To me, price-conscious borders on frugal - which I take to mean valuing base cost over all other aspects (quality, durability, brand, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

What about maximizer from this [sample usage](http://gretchenrubin.com/happiness_project/2006/06/are_you_a_satis/):

> Maximizers want to make the optimal decision

maximize from [Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/maximizer):

> to make the greatest or fullest use of

and finally bang for the buck from [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bang+for+the+buck):

> value for the money spent

these are when the emphasis is to get the best for the money.

Comment: Please mention the source for each definition, too. :)